# How to create a PeerJS connection

Tags: javascript, html, peerjs

I am trying to create a PeerJS connection where the host creates a connection by getting a generated Peer ID by calling `peer.generateID()`. The host should then get this ID on screen and share with his/her client to connect and record some information in the localStorage. However no Peer ID is generated for connection and no message displayed as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Peer to Peer Activity</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.peerjs.io/latest/peerjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Peer to Peer Activity</h1>

  <p>Select an option:</p>

  <button onclick="createHost()">Create Host</button>
  <button onclick="joinHost()">Join Host</button>

  <input type="text" id="messageInput" />
  <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>

  <div id="message"></div>

  <script>
    // Create a PeerJS object
    var peer = new PeerJS();

    // Create a data channel
    var dataChannel = peer.createDataChannel('my-channel');

    // Listen for incoming messages
    dataChannel.onmessage = function(event) {
      // Update the message on the screen
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = event.data;

      // Save the message to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('message', event.data);
    };

    // Create a host
    function createHost() {
      // Generate a peer ID
      var peerID = peer.generateID();

      // Create a new host session
      var session = peer.createSession({
        id: peerID
      });
      

      // Listen for incoming connections
      session.on('connection', function(connection) {
        // Accept the connection
        connection.accept();

        // Set the data channel for the connection
        dataChannel = connection.dataChannel;
      });

      // Update the message on the screen
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'You are now hosting a session. Share the following peer ID with the other device: ' + peerID;
    };

    // Join a host
    function joinHost() {
      // Get the peer ID of the host device
      var hostPeerID = document.getElementById('hostPeerID').value;

      // Connect to the host device
      peer.connect(hostPeerID);

      // Listen for incoming connections
      peer.on('connection', function(connection) {
        // Accept the connection
        connection.accept();

        // Set the data channel for the connection
        dataChannel = connection.dataChannel;
      });

      // Update the message on the screen
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'You are now connected to the host device.';
    };

    // Send a message
    function sendMessage() {
      // Get the message from the text input
      var message = document.getElementById('messageInput').value;

      // Send the message to the other device
      dataChannel.send(message);

      // Clear the text input
      document.getElementById('messageInput').value = '';
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get an assistance on why my code is not working as expected and how it should be written.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console, and if so, what?

Comment: I think the main problem is coming from ```peer.generateID()```. No ID is generated. How should I handle that. Is there any other workaround.